# C# BlockCypher Подписание Bitcoin транзакции

Tags: c#, bitcoin

Я использую BlockCypher API для работы в тестовой сети Bitcoin. Создание транзакции осуществляется в [2 этапа](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#creating-transactions): *New Transaction Endpoint* и *Send Transaction Endpoint*. Первый этап заключается в заполнении сервером полей объекта транзакции, второй - в локальном подписании приватным ключом. Данная ошибка возникает у меня на втором этапе:

```
{
   "errors":[
      {
         "error":"Error validating generated transaction: Error running script for input 0 referencing 5efa3d59dbdd391d8f8d277c49c6d9de7ae13f004190b8132ed6da203e14016b at 0: Script was NOT verified successfully."
      }
   ],
   "tx":{
      "block_height":-1,
      "block_index":-1,
      "hash":"f2b24467c1caa3181ab7effc8b23624c341d6f296fcb5bd4c49026ecc5b138e4",
      "addresses":[
         "mp9Cz49v2Nj2dfSmu4Lz9r91X1CF6hVHVz",
         "mwpG4fa4B3vSio81QEVPiDmA2Cgi26cnV4"
      ],
      "total":88900,
      "fees":11100,
      "size":226,
      "vsize":226,
      "preference":"low",
      "relayed_by":"92.101.184.223",
      "received":"2021-03-29T14:18:34.039933202Z",
      "ver":1,
      "double_spend":false,
      "vin_sz":1,
      "vout_sz":2,
      "confirmations":0,
      "inputs":[
         {
            "prev_hash":"5efa3d59dbdd391d8f8d277c49c6d9de7ae13f004190b8132ed6da203e14016b",
            "output_index":0,
            "script":"483045022100b83a6e3b3b3b997f83fd4ab13f4b1cbabdb69b883e96bbe97443889556b7523702200d2c4ee2e641e31b6f1ce2e20e2fda9bdedca21a668152d15471e040d542aede0121034593cfafe3723ff0396291415e5bc90ef46a1e5967af3fcaaeeb74420c2a72a4",
            "output_value":100000,
            "sequence":4294967295,
            "addresses":[
               "mp9Cz49v2Nj2dfSmu4Lz9r91X1CF6hVHVz"
            ],
            "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash",
            "age":1968449
         }
      ],
      "outputs":[
         {
            "value":50000,
            "script":"76a914b2c7eab66c1e7b1326e228ec7883ef055c21ce1488ac",
            "addresses":[
               "mwpG4fa4B3vSio81QEVPiDmA2Cgi26cnV4"
            ],
            "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"
         },
         {
            "value":38900,
            "script":"76a9145e9c3e438a489470ed2e8cca4bbb96501f2a827b88ac",
            "addresses":[
               "mp9Cz49v2Nj2dfSmu4Lz9r91X1CF6hVHVz"
            ],
            "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"
         }
      ]
   },
   "tosign":[
      ""
   ]
}
```

Использую метод `Sign` [отсюда](https://github.com/bscheiman/BlockCypher/blob/d6eca38fe2342ef3311686f19180324b5c95bfb1/Blockcypher.cs). Подскажите, как исправить ошибку и, желательно, использовать при этом библиотеку NBitcoin, так как она уже включена в проект с целью генерации Bitcoin адресов.

```
TXSkeleton unsignedTx = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TXSkeleton>(
    response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

unsignedTx.PubKeys = new List<string>();
unsignedTx.Signatures = new List<string>();
Sign(unsignedTx, address.PrivateKey.ToHex(), true, true, true);
```